# Python - Converting CSV file - lenght of an obiect

Tags: python, csv, converters, string-length

Got little problem here.

```
for row in reader:
    dane_wejsciowe.append(row)
```

I got some *.csv file I want to convert and my converter acts weird...
the function above takes all needed columns into an array and after that I am calling those columns to count the length of it:

```
for line in dane_wejsciowe:
    if len(line['Mnemonik']) > len_mnemonik:
        len_mnemonik += 1
```

After that I am printing the record `print(' - Mnemonik: ' + str(len_mnemonik))` and the result is `22` BUT the longest one is `BEUS_EnergyDriveAvgDist` which contains `_` and I suspect its not counting special letters

and my "idiotic" idea to print it into a file was

```
   if len(i['Mnemonik']) < len_mnemonik:
        a = len_mnemonik - len(i['Mnemonik']) + 1
    else:
        a = 1
    jsfile.write(i['Mnemonik']),
    jsfile.write((' ')*a),
```

Any1 have better idea to do it? :)

Comment: sorry for no specify the question. I need to print it with a number of white spaces to make it nice in columns. That's why I have else: a = 1 because if script hit the longest one there still have to be one space - to make a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're using `csv.reader()` to gather each row, which automatically parses each row into a list using the specified delimiter in the command (default is comma). Because of this, your variable `dane_wejsciowe` is a list(?) of lists, where each outer element (e.g. `dane_wejsciowe[0]`) is a row of the CSV file, and each inner element (e.g. `dane_wejsciowe[0][0]`) is a cell in that row of the CSV. Therefore your `len()==22` has nothing to do with the text `BEUS_EnergyDriveAvgDist`, but tells you the the number of columns in your CSV.

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(line['Mnemonik']) > len_mnemonik:
    len_mnemonik += 1
```

I don't know why you think the code above would eventually give you the maximum value of `len_mnemonik`, particularly the `+= 1` part. Rather you should do:

```
if len(line['Mnemonik']) > len_mnemonik:
    len_mnemonik = len(line['Mnemonik'])
```

or:

```
len_mnemonik = max(len_mnemonik, len(line['Mnemonik']))
```

(no if statement)

Comment: cuz its in a loop `for line in dane_wejsciowe:
    if len(line['Mnemonik']) > len_mnemonik:
        len_mnemonik += 1`

Comment: @OskarGarczyński I know it's in a loop, but your logic doesn't make sense. If there's two lines in the CSV then `len_mnemonik += 1` will happen just twice (or less) so `len_mnemonik` will be at most 2 by the end.